# Concordance and homology cobordism

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 4-manifolds

If two knots $K_1$ and $K_2$ in $S^3$ are smoothly concordant, then for any rational number $r$, the $r$-surgeries $S^3_r(K_1)$ and $S^3_r(K_2)$ are homology cobordant. Is the converse true? What if $r$ is assumed to be an integer? (Presumably the answer is no in both cases.)

Thanks to Yasui (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.02551.pdf), we now know that for any integer $n$, there exists a pair of non-concordant knots whose $n$-surgeries are homeomorphic. Likewise, Cochran-Franklin-Hedden-Horn's construction of non-concordant knots whose $0$-surgeries are homology cobordant can be modified for other integers $n$. However, neither of those constructions produces a single pair of non-concordant knots whose $n$-surgeries are homology cobordant for all $n$.

One way to construct a counterexample would be to exhibit a winding-number-$1$ knot $P$ in the solid torus that is not concordant in $S^1 \times D^2 \times I$ to the core circle, but which has the property that the knot $P(n)$ gotten by an $n$-framed unknotted embedding of $S^1 \times D^2$ in $S^3$ is slice for all $n$. The latter property shows that for any knot $K$, $n$-surgery on the satellite knot $P(K)$ is homology cobordant to $n$-surgery on $K$. It might then be possible to use $\tau$, $s$, or some other invariant to show that $K$ and $P(K)$ are not concordant.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Adam! Congrats on starting out with a "Nice Question" http://mathoverflow.net/help/badges.